# Let $x \in \Bbb R $. Prove that if $x^5+4x^4+3x^3-x^2+3x-4 \ge 0$, then $x \ge 0$

Tags: inequality, polynomials

Let $x \in \Bbb R $. Prove that if $x^5+4x^4+3x^3-x^2+3x-4 \ge 0$, then $x \ge 0$

My try:

I tried to factor the polynomial, but i couldn't do it. I don't know how to proceed  in this problem.

It's an exercise from a class in my university. The last exercise and is the only that i can't do and i'm looking for some hints.

Comment: There's something wrong with your expression.

Comment: Yes,probably a typo.

Comment: The question is lacking some key context, such as the source of this particular polynomial and why we are interested in it.

Comment: @Yadati Kiran: that comment addresses the converse of the problem

Comment: Note that when $x<0$, every term in this expression except $4x^4$ is negative.

Comment: @Rodrigo Pizarro : You may try to prove the negation of the statement. It is easy for $x<-1$ as $x^5$ is the dominating term. You might have to prove for $-1\leq x<0$.

Comment: @YadatiKiran Somewhat correct. Sure, $x^5$ is the dominating term, but the case work is still annoying. (You have to deal with $-4<x<0$) I don't see why your first comment is pertinent

Comment: @DonThousand : Sorry about that. Its absurd now I think about it.

Comment: I think i can prove it by contrapositive. Should i edit my post and put the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because
$$0\leq x^5+4x^4+3x^3-x^2+3x-4<x^5+4x^4+3x^3-x^2+3x=$$
$$=x(x^4+4x^3+3x^2-x+3)=x\left(\left(x^2+2x-\frac{2}{3}\right)^2+\frac{1}{9}(3x^2+15x+23)\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

If $x<0$, then
$$ x^5+4x^4+3x^3-x^2+3x-4 <x^5+3x^3+3x-4 
=\frac{(x^2+1)^3-1}{x}-4<0$$

Comment: This is a lot prettier of a factorization than the one I was using. Sheesh.

Comment: I undestood the last step, but i don't understand why the first step $x^5+4x^4+3x^3-x^2+3x-4 <x^5+3x^3+3x-4 $ is true. Sorry if i'm misunderstanding something trivial.